# Creating a Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC image

Tags: windows-10, iot

I'm looking to install Windows 10 IoT LTSC on a compatible IoT device, and I have found a [walkthrough page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/iot-ent-get-the-tools-you-need) in the MSDN.

Since I want to use my computer as the *technician PC*, I installed Windows ADK with Windows PE, but I can't seem to find where I can download or acquire the "Windows 10 IoT Enterprise LTSC OPK" or either of the two ISOs named in the instructions.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Do they come with Windows 10 by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 10 IoT LTSC Version and the ISOs you are looking for are included in the paid Visual Studio Professional subscription.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing/

There can you download a list of the software, tools, etc. included in the subscription.

[Download link for the list](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/4/15454442-CF17-47B9-A65D-DF84EF88511B/Visual_Studio_by_Subscription_Level.xlsx)

Comment: How can I extract the files I need once I have a subscription, where in Visual Studio would I do that exactly?

Comment: You should it find there: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads/